# Flask RESTPlus API URL not found error when working with Blueprint and Namespaces - 404 not found error

Tags: python, flask, flask-restplus

I am working with my first flask-RESTplus application and running into issues. Here is how my project is structured:

```
proj/
  - endpoints/
    - __init__.py
    - example1.py
    - example2.py
      
  - app.py
```

This is what I have in my `__init__.py`:

```
from flask import Blueprint
from flask_restplus import Api
    

blueprint1 = Blueprint('api', __name__)
api = Api(blueprint1,version='1.0', title='Sample API',
    description='A sample API',
)

ns = api.namespace('todos', description='todo')
sample1_ns = api.namespace('flask-todos')
```

My `example1.py` has below code:

```
from flask import Flask , request, Blueprint
from flask_restplus import Api, Resource, fields, Namespace
from endpoints import ns

todo = ns.model('Todo', {
    'task': fields.String(required=True, description='The task details')
})

@ns.route('/api_route1', endpoint = 'route1-endpoint')
class Todo(Resource):
    '''Shows a list of all todos, and lets you POST to add new tasks'''
    @ns.doc(parser=parser)
    @ns.expect(todo)
    #@ns.marshal_list_with(todo)
    def post(self):
        #processing code
        return message
```

My `example2.py` has below code:

```
from flask import Flask , request, Blueprint
from flask_restplus import Api, Resource, fields, Namespace]   
from endpoints import sample1_ns

todo2 = sample1_ns.model('Todo2', {
    'task': fields.String(required=True, description='The task details')
})

@sample1_ns.route('/api_route2', endpoint = 'route2-endpoint')
class Todos2(Resource):
    '''Shows a list of all todos, and lets you POST to add new tasks'''
    @sample1_ns.doc(parser=parser)
    @sample1_ns.expect(todo2)
    
    def post(self):
        #processing code
        return message
```

from `app.py`, this is how I try to invoke the app:

```
from flask import Flask , request, Blueprint
from flask_restplus import Api, Resource, fields
from werkzeug.middleware.proxy_fix import ProxyFix 
from endpoints import blueprint1 

app = Flask(__name__)
app.wsgi_app = ProxyFix(app.wsgi_app)
app.register_blueprint(blueprint1)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

When I run my app.py, it runs without any error but when I try to reach to my API route by going to `http://127.0.0.1:5000/api_route1` or `http://127.0.0.1:5000/api_route2`, I get `404 Page Not found` error and it says `The requested URL was not found on the server` (on Postman APP)

Not sure where the error is and how to make the corrections.

**Note:** I have python 3.8 and flask-restplus 0.11.0

Answer (score 0):

Add the methods keyword. From this:

`@sample1_ns.route('/api_route2', endpoint = 'route2-endpoint')`

to this:

`@sample1_ns.route('/api_route2', endpoint = 'route2-endpoint', methods=['GET'])`

Comment: It's still the same. I added the methods keyword but still get the same `404 Not Found` error.

Answer (score 0):

Change the code as below to work -

In `proj/endpoints/__init__.py`:

```
from flask import Blueprint
from flask_restplus import Api


blueprint1 = Blueprint('api', __name__)
api = Api(blueprint1,version='1.0', title='Sample API',
     description='A sample API',
)

sample1_ns = api.namespace('todos', description='todo')
```

In `__init__.py`:

```
from flask_restplus import Api
from proj.endpoint.example1.py import ns sample1_ns ns1
from proj.endpoint.example2.py import ns sample1_ns ns2

api = Api("Proj apis", version='1.0', title='Sample API',
    description='A sample API',
)

# register namespaces
api.add_namespace(ns1)
api.add_namespace(ns2)
```

Keep as it is the `example1.py` and `example2.py`.